# SAS: How to combine a text and date field

Tags: sas, type-conversion, concatenation

I need to combine an ID number with a date field to create a unique identifier.  It's a nineteen character ID field and a date formatted YYYY-MM-DD

```
| ID_Field          | Date     |
|-------------------|----------|
|87654321G0123456789|2017-05-18|
|76543218H9876543210|2020-02-25|
```

My efforts to concatenate the date, convert the date to text and combine, use the coalesce function, compress have all failed.

Please offer suggestions

Comment: Take a look at the `cats()` and `catx()` functions.  They will concatenate all variables passed in, perform type conversions, strip leading and trailing spaces, etc...

Comment: Why do you need to combine the two fields? You already two categorical variables whose combination (by your statement) is unique.

Answer (score 3):

A format in SAS is used to convert values to text.  So use the YYMMDD format to convert your date field into the string you need.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length uid $29;
  uid = cats(id_field,put(date,yymmdd10.));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

the oldest method to concatenate strings in SAS is the operator: ||

```
data want;
  set have;
    new_ID = ID_Field  || Date;
run;
```

Notice that the concatenation operator doesn’t remove leading and/or trailing blanks.If you would like to use the concatenation operator but get rid of whitespaces, you should add the [STRIP](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n0xk6tl87f4b4qn1sp1ywen1ntan.htm) function.